# How to get the IsSyncing to TRUE on a QUOTE in test class?

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read my question, this may be a really stupid question but I have been banging my head all morning into finding the answer. I looked at the Quote Schema as well as the Developer docs [Quote Doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm)

I was not able to find a way to create the 'push' of the Sync button. As well when I try to change the checkbox to True in code

```
Quote testQuote = new Quote(
                        name= 'JFTestQuote',Agreement_Term__c = '12 Months', Payment_Terms__c = '1005 with Purchase Order',
                        OpportunityId = testOpp.Id, IsSyncing = TRUE
                        );
```

I get an error stating : *Field is not writeable.*

I need to have my quote as synced in order to test my trigger, as there may be many quotes in the opportunity but only the synced would be of importance.

Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of marking the sync at the quote level you'll need to mark it at the opportunity level via the `Opportunity.SyncedQuoteId` field.  After doing this the `Quote.IsSyncing` field will be true.

Answer (score 3):

This blog post (http://blog.softwareallies.com/2010/08/salesfoce-syncing-quote-in-apex.html) explains what triggers the syncing to happen.

Comment: Thank you Mike, the blog had everything I was looking for.

Comment: This blog post is no longer live, unfortunately.